# Swift DispatchSourceTimer makes unrelated views reload every second

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uikit, swiftui

[28/10/2019: I have recreated the same test project with UIKit... unsurprisingly, the timer does not make any of the view controller views reload!!! So this looks like a SwiftUI bug.  UIKIt version: https://github.com/DominikButz/DispatchSourceTimerUIKit.git]

[19/10/2019: Please check out https://github.com/DominikButz/DispatchTimerSwiftUIReloadBug.git for better understanding of the issue. When you launch this in the simulator, just tap on "Launch timer". Check the debug console, you will see that all views are reloaded every second.]

### Original post:

I'm creating an iOS app in SwiftUI for which I need to use a timer. I'm posting the class below.

The timer works fine (except for not continuing when the app is in the background, but that is another story...). As you can see in the resumeTimer function, the timer is set to repeat every second.

There is a view in which a Text label gets updated every time the timer fires. This works fine. However, the problem is that other views that are loaded after the timer starts all get reloaded every time the timer fires, that means every second. e.g. an unrelated list (*where the timer text label is not placed*) gets reloaded every second, which makes it unusable.

I know this because when I pause or cancel the timer through the user interface, the debugger shows that the views don't get reloaded every second anymore. I placed a breakpoint (with the option "continue after evaluation") in the body of each of those views and the debugger shows that the views gets reloaded every time the timer fires.

The timer class below is created in the SceneDelegate and then passed to the Content view as environment object. I had it as ObservedObject before only in the view where the timer Text label is placed, but the result is the same. See below a view that gets reloaded when the timer fires... (gif screenshot).

Could this be a bug in SwiftUI? or might there be an error in my timer class? thanks for any hints in the right direction

[image: the view gets reloaded every time the timer fires]

Here is the content view

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var workoutModel: WorkoutModel
    @EnvironmentObject  var workoutWatch: WorkoutStopWatchTimer

    @State var selectedMenuIndex  = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.selectedMenuIndex)
    @State private var workoutViewPresenting = false

    func setMenuIndex() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedMenuIndex, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.selectedMenuIndex)
    }

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection:$selectedMenuIndex) {

            WorkoutSelectionView(workoutViewPresenting: self.$workoutViewPresenting).onAppear(perform: self.setMenuIndex)
                 .tabItem {
                     Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                     Text("Start Workout")
            }.tag(0)


            Text("History").onAppear(perform: self.setMenuIndex)  // I set a breakpoint here (with continue after evaluation checked)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("History")
            }.tag(1)

            ExerciseListView().onAppear(perform: self.setMenuIndex) // I set a breakpoint here (with continue after evaluation checked)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Exercises")
                }.tag(2)


            Text("Profile").onAppear(perform: self.setMenuIndex)
                .tabItem {
                     Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                     Text("Profile")
            }.tag(3)

        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$workoutViewPresenting) {
            // the timer is passed to this view in which a Text label is updated every second to show the time
            WorkoutView().environmentObject(self.workoutModel).environmentObject(self.workoutWatch)
        }

    }

}
```

debugger console: see the comments I put in the content view above to see where I placed the breakpoints. I did not open and close those views that many times, they are reloaded automatically every second when the timer is running.

...
3 loading History
3 loading Exercise List View
4 loading History
4 loading Exercise List View
5 loading History
5 loading Exercise List View
6 loading History
6 loading Exercise List View
7 loading History
7 loading Exercise List View
...

class WorkoutStopWatchTimer: ObservableObject {

```
   private var sourceTimer: DispatchSourceTimer?

    private let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "stopwatch.timer", qos: .background, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .never, target: nil)
    private var counter: Int = 0  // seconds

    var endDate: Date?
    var duration: TimeInterval?

    @Published var timeDisplayString = "0:00"

    var paused = false

   var isActive: Bool {
        return  self.sourceTimer != nil
    }

    func start() {
        self.paused = false

        guard let _ = self.sourceTimer else {
            self.startTimer()
            return
        }

        self.resumeTimer()
    }

     func finish() {

        guard self.sourceTimer != nil else {return}
        self.endDate = Date()
        self.duration = TimeInterval(exactly: Double(self.counter))

        self.sourceTimer?.setEventHandler {}
        self.sourceTimer?.cancel()
        if self.paused == true {
            self.sourceTimer?.resume()
        }
        self.sourceTimer = nil
        self.reset()

     }

    func pause() {
          self.paused = true
          self.sourceTimer?.suspend()

      }

     private func reset() {
         self.timeDisplayString = "0:00"
         self.counter = 0

     }

    private func startTimer() {
        self.sourceTimer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags.strict,
                                                          queue: self.queue)

        self.resumeTimer()
    }

    private func resumeTimer() {
        self.sourceTimer?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
          //  self.eventHandler = {
                self?.updateTimer()
          //  }
        }

        self.sourceTimer?.schedule(deadline: .now(),
                                   repeating: 1)
        self.sourceTimer?.resume()
    }

    private func updateTimer() {
        self.counter += 1

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timeDisplayString = WorkoutStopWatchTimer.convertCountToTimeString(counter: self.counter)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please delete all code that's not essential to show this issue (which seems to be almost everything). Then add the essential part(s) of your SwiftUI code (which is completely missing now).

Comment: sorry, I put the timer class at the end and removed the extension (which only creates the timer string). I posted the Content view to understand the whole concept better. Please check the comments in the content view code. the gif shows the Exercise List View which has the tag 2 in the TabView.  the problem is that I don't know which part of my code causes those views to reload every second  - it must be in the timer class or it is a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: I think it is useless to post the code of each of the four views which has a tag in the TabView. This is because the bug is not in those views. This is obvious because the "History"-view is currently only a Text. But no matter if the view is just a Text or a lot more complex like the ExerciseListView, once the timer is running, they all are reloaded every second.

Comment: It isn't clear from your screenshot where the timer should appear but I think you need to put the tableview and your timer into a VStack so that it isn't reloaded.

Comment: The timer Text label is not in that Exercise List view that you can see as gif. I have recreated the project in a simplified version just to demonstrate the reloading problem. It is possible that I completely misunderstand the usage of DispatchSourceTimer in Swift... so I'm not sure if that behaviour is intended or not. https://github.com/DominikButz/DispatchTimerSwiftUIReloadBug.git . When you launch this in the simulator, just tap on Launch timer. Check the debug console, you will see that all views are reloaded every second.

Comment: If a state variable changes and it is referred to in the `view` getter function body, the `view` getter function is called and the view is redrawn. Your state variable changes every second so the view is redrawn every second.

Comment: thanks for the reply. strictly speaking it's not a State variable but an environment object with a @Published variable. But that doesn't explain why all the other views are reloaded every second although they don't have the watch timer as instance variable or the watchTimer.timeDisplayString  in the body (checkout github.com/DominikButz/DispatchTimerSwiftUIReloadBug.git ).only the TimerView has the watchTimer.timeDisplayString in the body.

Comment: I have found a workaround in the meantime, check out the latest commit  https://github.com/DominikButz/DispatchTimerSwiftUIReloadBug.git . The trick is to use State variable for the timerDisplayString. Thus the eventHandler of the TimerManger must be set in the TimerView (the view that contains the Text label showing the elapsed time). Other views that are not related to the Timer View are not reloaded every second any more.

Comment: ... However, I have a sheet (modal presentation) attached to the TimerView in my original app (not in that git repository). This is the gif that you can see in my post above. This problem still persists. the trick is to nullify the timer eventHandler and then reset it once that modal sheet disappears.